# Amend Sort custom binding to return property corresponding to sort type

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

This fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pyCTN/230/ shows an application that creates observable arrays from JSON data and uses a custom binding to sort those arrays by Sum, Count or Average.

At the moment, all 3 properties (Sum, Count, Average) are displayed:

```
<span class="input-group-addon" data-bind="text: FItemSum"></span>
<span class="input-group-addon" data-bind="text: FItemCount"></span>
<span class="input-group-addon" data-bind="text: FItemAvrg"></span>
```

I need to either display only the sorted property. E.g:

```
<span class="input-group-addon" data-bind="text: FItemSum, visible: someBinding"></span>
<span class="input-group-addon" data-bind="text: FItemCount, visible: someBinding""></span>
<span class="input-group-addon" data-bind="text: FItemAvrg, visible: someBinding""></span>
```

Or return only one property containing the sorted data. E.g:

```
<span class="input-group-addon" data-bind="text: FItemSortType></span>
```

Does knockout have an elegant way of achieving this?

I'm already traversing the DOM using Jquery to set element text:

```
var el = $(element).closest('div').children()[0];
el.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(prop.title + ' '), el.firstChild);
```

which feels a bit nasty but if it's the best/only way to achieve my goal, I'm okay with it.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you need knockout binding for? Could you consider add computed observable with sorted array and current sort item?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, knockout has filtered arrays: bind the select on the filtered array, and have a ko.observable() filter that you change via a text box, or dropdown, or whatever you want

```
self.yourFilteredArray = ko.computed(function() {
    if(!self.yourFilter()) {
        return self.theWholeUnfilteredArray(); 
    } else {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.theWholeUnfilteredArray(), function(item) {
            return item.whatEverPropertyYouWant == self.currentFilter();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed not a very elegant way as you "bypass" Knockout with jQuery. I don't quite see the need for a custom binding, as what you want can be achieved with a simple `click` binding. 
First, you want to sort the values per FListGroup, not per viewModel. So your sort-related properties should be available on the FListGroup, like so (see inline comments for explanation):

```
function FListGroup(title, fListCount, fItemGroup) {
    var self = this;
    self.Title = title;
    self.FListCount = fListCount;
    self.sorttype = [
        {title:'Score',sortPropertyName:'FItemSum'},
        {title:'Count',sortPropertyName:'FItemCount'},
        {title:'Average',sortPropertyName:'FItemAvrg'}
    ];
    // this property holds the current selected sort type by index, 
    // so 0 => 'Score' set as default   
    self.chosenSort = ko.observable(0);
    // The sort inside is only required if data should be sorted on page load
    self.FItemGroup = ko.observableArray(fItemGroup.sort(function (left, right) {
        var x = self.sorttype[self.chosenSort()].sortPropertyName;
        return  left[x] == right[x] ? 0 : left[x] > right[x] ? -1 : 1;
    }));
    self.setChosenSort = function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < self.sorttype.length; i++) {
            if (self.sorttype[i].sortPropertyName === data.sortPropertyName) {
            self.chosenSort(i); }
        }
        self.FItemGroup.sort(function (left, right) {
            var x = self.sorttype[self.chosenSort()].sortPropertyName;
            return  left[x] == right[x] ? 0 : left[x] > right[x] ? -1 : 1;
        })
    };
    // Function to determine whether the value-column should be visible,
    // Argument should be an index from self.sorttype array
    self.toggleColumns = function(data) { return data === self.chosenSort(); };
}
```

So in your view model, the only thing that actually remains is the AJAX call & the `test` array.
Now for the view, in your dropdown (HTML):

```
<a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
   // This is what replaces your jQuery DOM replace //
   <span data-bind="text: sorttype[chosenSort()].title"></span> 
   <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" data-bind="foreach: sorttype" role="menu">
   <li>
      <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.setChosenSort, text: $data.title"></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Note: You don't need to explicitly pass parameters to `$parent.setChosenSort` because by default `$data` and `event` are passed.
And for the item columns:

```
<span class="input-group-addon" data-bind="text: FItemSum, 
  visible: $parent.toggleColumns(0)"></span>
<span class="input-group-addon" data-bind="text: FItemCount, 
  visible: $parent.toggleColumns(1)"></span>
<span class="input-group-addon" data-bind="text: FItemAvrg, 
  visible: $parent.toggleColumns(2)"></span>
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/pyCTN/239/